# how to set user defaults with folder name

Tags: cocoa, nsuserdefaults

I hope to set the user defaults to

```
~/Library/Preference
```

under the folder name 'MyFolder', plist name is

```
com.mycompany.myapp.plist
```

Do I need to create the plist file and the folder by myself or the system create automatically?

Is there any tutorial?

Comment: I am not sure what the question is, every project will automatically create a plist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [User Defaults System](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/UserDefaults.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059-BCIDJFHD). The User Defaults classes (particularly [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) manage the creation and location of the preferences file and allow you to easily read and write preferences data.

By default, the User Defaults system creates a preferences file with your app's bundle ID and the `plist` extension under the `~/Library/Preferences` folder, however you should not rely on this behaviour. If you use the API you don't need to know the location of the file as it's not important.

You should never create or manage the preferences file directly, you should always use the API.

Comment: “… you should not rely on this behaviour.” To be clear: It *will* create the storage it needs automatically; you don't need to create any files yourself for it to store things in. You should not rely on the storage being in any particular place or format.